# Square detection doesn't find squares

Tags: c++, c, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I'm using the program **squares.c** available in the samples of OpenCV libraries. It works well with every image, but I really can't figure it out why it doesn't recognize the square drawn in that image

[image]

After **CANNY**:
[image]

After **DILATE**:
[image]

The **RESULT** image (in red)
http://img267.imageshack.us/img267/8016/resultuq.jpg

As you can see, the square is NOT detected.

After the detection I need to extract the area contained in the square...How is it possible without a ROI?

Comment: Your images seem to be missing. Is there any chance you could reupload or recreate them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The source code below presents a small variation of the **Square Detector** program. It's not perfect, but it illustrates one way to approach your problem.

You can *diff* this code to the original and check all the changes that were made, but the main ones are:

- Decrease the number of threshold levels to **2**.
- In the beginning of `findSquares()`, **dilate** the image to detect the thin white square, and then **blur** the entire image so the algorithm doesn't detect the sea and the sky as individual squares.

Once compiled, run the application with the following syntax: `./app <image>`

```
// The "Square Detector" program.
// It loads several images sequentially and tries to find squares in
// each image

#include "highgui.h"
#include "cv.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void help()
{
        cout <<
        "\nA program using pyramid scaling, Canny, contours, contour simpification and\n"
        "memory storage (it's got it all folks) to find\n"
        "squares in a list of images pic1-6.png\n"
        "Returns sequence of squares detected on the image.\n"
        "the sequence is stored in the specified memory storage\n"
        "Call:\n"
        "./squares\n"
    "Using OpenCV version %s\n" << CV_VERSION << "\n" << endl;
}


int thresh = 50, N = 2; // karlphillip: decreased N to 2, was 11.
const char* wndname = "Square Detection Demo";

// helper function:
// finds a cosine of angle between vectors
// from pt0->pt1 and from pt0->pt2
double angle( Point pt1, Point pt2, Point pt0 )
{
    double dx1 = pt1.x - pt0.x;
    double dy1 = pt1.y - pt0.y;
    double dx2 = pt2.x - pt0.x;
    double dy2 = pt2.y - pt0.y;
    return (dx1*dx2 + dy1*dy2)/sqrt((dx1*dx1 + dy1*dy1)*(dx2*dx2 + dy2*dy2) + 1e-10);
}

// returns sequence of squares detected on the image.
// the sequence is stored in the specified memory storage
void findSquares( const Mat& image, vector<vector<Point> >& squares )
{
    squares.clear();

    Mat pyr, timg, gray0(image.size(), CV_8U), gray;

    // karlphillip: dilate the image so this technique can detect the white square,
    Mat out(image);
    dilate(out, out, Mat(), Point(-1,-1));
    // then blur it so that the ocean/sea become one big segment to avoid detecting them as 2 big squares.
    medianBlur(out, out, 7);

    // down-scale and upscale the image to filter out the noise
    pyrDown(out, pyr, Size(out.cols/2, out.rows/2));
    pyrUp(pyr, timg, out.size());
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;

    // find squares in every color plane of the image
    for( int c = 0; c < 3; c++ )
    {
        int ch[] = {c, 0};
        mixChannels(&timg, 1, &gray0, 1, ch, 1);

        // try several threshold levels
        for( int l = 0; l < N; l++ )
        {
            // hack: use Canny instead of zero threshold level.
            // Canny helps to catch squares with gradient shading
            if( l == 0 )
            {
                // apply Canny. Take the upper threshold from slider
                // and set the lower to 0 (which forces edges merging)
                Canny(gray0, gray, 0, thresh, 5);
                // dilate canny output to remove potential
                // holes between edge segments
                dilate(gray, gray, Mat(), Point(-1,-1));
            }
            else
            {
                // apply threshold if l!=0:
                //     tgray(x,y) = gray(x,y) < (l+1)*255/N ? 255 : 0
                gray = gray0 >= (l+1)*255/N;
            }

            // find contours and store them all as a list
            findContours(gray, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

            vector<Point> approx;

            // test each contour
            for( size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
            {
                // approximate contour with accuracy proportional
                // to the contour perimeter
                approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), approx, arcLength(Mat(contours[i]), true)*0.02, true);

                // square contours should have 4 vertices after approximation
                // relatively large area (to filter out noisy contours)
                // and be convex.
                // Note: absolute value of an area is used because
                // area may be positive or negative - in accordance with the
                // contour orientation
                if( approx.size() == 4 &&
                    fabs(contourArea(Mat(approx))) > 1000 &&
                    isContourConvex(Mat(approx)) )
                {
                    double maxCosine = 0;

                    for( int j = 2; j < 5; j++ )
                    {
                        // find the maximum cosine of the angle between joint edges
                        double cosine = fabs(angle(approx[j%4], approx[j-2], approx[j-1]));
                        maxCosine = MAX(maxCosine, cosine);
                    }

                    // if cosines of all angles are small
                    // (all angles are ~90 degree) then write quandrange
                    // vertices to resultant sequence
                    if( maxCosine < 0.3 )
                        squares.push_back(approx);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


// the function draws all the squares in the image
void drawSquares( Mat& image, const vector<vector<Point> >& squares )
{
    for( size_t i = 0; i < squares.size(); i++ )
    {
        const Point* p = &squares[i][0];
        int n = (int)squares[i].size();
        polylines(image, &p, &n, 1, true, Scalar(0,255,0), 3, CV_AA);
    }

    imshow(wndname, image);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        cout << "Usage: ./program <file>" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

//    static const char* names[] = { "pic1.png", "pic2.png", "pic3.png",
//        "pic4.png", "pic5.png", "pic6.png", 0 };
    static const char* names[] = { argv[1], 0 };

    help();
    namedWindow( wndname, 1 );
    vector<vector<Point> > squares;

    for( int i = 0; names[i] != 0; i++ )
    {
        Mat image = imread(names[i], 1);
        if( image.empty() )
        {
            cout << "Couldn't load " << names[i] << endl;
            continue;
        }

        findSquares(image, squares);
        drawSquares(image, squares);
        imwrite("out.jpg", image);

        int c = waitKey();
        if( (char)c == 27 )
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Outputs**:

[image]

Comment: thank you karlphillip...with your correction now the script works fine. But if I want to extract a sub-image containing only the area included in the square? Is it possible? (in this case we haven't a ROI but only a sequence of squares)

Comment: Yes, you need to create a `cv::Mat` from a set of 4 `cv::Point`.  Let's keep it one question per thread since Stackoverflow is not a chat. If you have more questions, feel free to ask them in new threads.

Comment: But just to illustrate the procedure on this case, since the application has a vector of squares, you should do something like: `for (size_t x = 0; x < squares.size(); x++) { Rect roi(squares[x][0].x, squares[x][0].y, squares[x][1].x - squares[x][0].x, squares[x][3].y - squares[x][0].y); Mat subimage(image, roi); }` and it will generate a new **Mat** called `subimage` for all the squares detected in the original image.

Comment: **Remember:** the points detected in the image may not represent a perfect square (as you can see in the image above) but the code I just suggested to you *assumes* they do.

Comment: karl, thank you for your kindness. As you suggested I created a new thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755647/opencv-extract-area-of-an-image-from-a-vector-of-squares

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest that your square in this image is too thin.  The first step in squares.c is to scale the image down and back up to reduce noise before passing to the Canny edge detector.

The scaling convolves with a 5x5 kernel, so in your case this could result in losing any gradient in such a thin edge.

Try making your square's edges at least 5 pixels if you are going to overlay them on a continuous background.

Comment: Unfortunately the square is already drawn, I have only to extract it