# opencv square detection sample detect the window lining and when i use imageroi it crops the whole image

Tags: opencv

i am currently trying to detect the boxes in an image and then i want to crop the detected boxes to use it on my project...but, the square detection samples of opencv also detect the lining of the image...so, the question is how can i only detect the boxes in the image??i am using opencv244, c++...just for the record, i've searched in here regarding this topic, but i couldn't get any ideas...any help would be appreciated, thanks!
Here is the link to my images...

1. the original image : http://www.flickr.com/photos/94841531@N08/8631367890/in/photostream/lightbox/
2. the detected boxes : http://www.flickr.com/photos/94841531@N08/8631368138/in/photostream/lightbox/

Comment: Could you check widht and height of the the found contour and dismiss the line object?

Comment: no, i'm quite new to opencv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just **ignore the largest square**.

In **squares.cpp* there's this function:

```
static void findSquares( const Mat& image, vector<vector<Point> >& squares )
{

}
```

which receives a `Mat` and a `vector<vector<Point> >`. So after this function is called, the green rectangles were not draw yet in the original `image` and you can iterate on `squares` to **filter out the largest rectangle found in the input image**.

You can take a [look at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13532779/176769) to check **how to identify the largest square** found in the image.

After that, you might want to [check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7756000/176769) to **extract an area of an image from a vector of squares**.

Remember, it's `drawSquares()` that draws the green stuff on the image.

Comment: hi, i've tested your solution, it worked...but, what should i do if i want to filter out the smallest square in the image??i've tried playing with the code, but nothing seems to change

Comment: Since that code finds the largest square, finding the smallest square is the exact opposite logic.