# Extract words in rectangles from text

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, extract, bufferedimage

I am struggling to extract fast and efficiently words that are in rectangles from a BufferedImage.
For example I have the following page : ( edit! ) the image is scanned, so it can contain noise, skewing and distortion.  
[image]

How can I extract the following images without the rectangle :
( edit! ) I can use OpenCv or any other library, but I'm absolutely new to advanced image processing techniques. 
[image]

**EDIT**

I've used the method suggested by `karlphillip` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427759/image-processing-and-extraction-of-characters/20624819#20624819) and it works decent.
Here is the code :

```
    package ro.ubbcluj.detection;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfByte;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

public class RectangleDetection {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    Mat image = loadImage();
    Mat grayscale = convertToGrayscale(image);

    Mat treshold = tresholdImage(grayscale);
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = findContours(treshold);
    Mat contoursImage = fillCountours(contours, grayscale);
    Mat grayscaleWithContours = convertToGrayscale(contoursImage);
    Mat tresholdGrayscaleWithContours = tresholdImage(grayscaleWithContours);
    Mat eroded = erodeAndDilate(tresholdGrayscaleWithContours);
    List<MatOfPoint> squaresFound = findSquares(eroded);
    Mat squaresDrawn = Rectangle.drawSquares(grayscale, squaresFound);
    BufferedImage convertedImage = convertMatToBufferedImage(squaresDrawn);
    displayImage(convertedImage);
}

private static List<MatOfPoint> findSquares(Mat eroded) {
    return Rectangle.findSquares(eroded);
}

private static Mat erodeAndDilate(Mat input) {
    int erosion_type = Imgproc.MORPH_RECT;
    int erosion_size = 5;
    Mat result = new Mat();
    Mat element = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(erosion_type, new Size(2 * erosion_size + 1, 2 * erosion_size + 1));
    Imgproc.erode(input, result, element);
    Imgproc.dilate(result, result, element);
    return result;
}

private static Mat convertToGrayscale(Mat input) {
    Mat grayscale = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(input, grayscale, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    return grayscale;
}

private static Mat fillCountours(List<MatOfPoint> contours, Mat image) {
    Mat result = image.clone();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(result, result, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGB);
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
        Imgproc.drawContours(result, contours, i, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), -1, 8, new Mat(), 0, new Point());
    }
    return result;
}

private static List<MatOfPoint> findContours(Mat image) {
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
    Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
    Imgproc.findContours(image, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    return contours;
}

private static Mat detectLinesHough(Mat img) {
    Mat lines = new Mat();
    int threshold = 80;
    int minLineLength = 10;
    int maxLineGap = 5;
    double rho = 0.4;
    Imgproc.HoughLinesP(img, lines, rho, Math.PI / 180, threshold, minLineLength, maxLineGap);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(img, img, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGB);
    System.out.println(lines.cols());
    for (int x = 0; x < lines.cols(); x++) {
        double[] vec = lines.get(0, x);
        double x1 = vec[0], y1 = vec[1], x2 = vec[2], y2 = vec[3];
        Point start = new Point(x1, y1);
        Point end = new Point(x2, y2);
        Core.line(lines, start, end, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 3);
    }
    return img;
}

static BufferedImage convertMatToBufferedImage(Mat mat) throws IOException {
    MatOfByte matOfByte = new MatOfByte();
    Highgui.imencode(".jpg", mat, matOfByte);
    byte[] byteArray = matOfByte.toArray();
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
    return ImageIO.read(in);

}

static void displayImage(BufferedImage image) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

private static Mat tresholdImage(Mat img) {
    Mat treshold = new Mat();
    Imgproc.threshold(img, treshold, 225, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);
    return treshold;
}

private static Mat tresholdImage2(Mat img) {
    Mat treshold = new Mat();
    Imgproc.threshold(img, treshold, -1, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV + Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
    return treshold;
}

private static Mat loadImage() {
    return Highgui
            .imread("E:\\Programs\\Eclipse Workspace\\LicentaWorkspace\\OpenCvRectangleDetection\\src\\img\\form3.jpg");
}
```

}

and the Rectangle class

```
    package ro.ubbcluj.detection;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint2f;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

public class Rectangle {
static List<MatOfPoint> findSquares(Mat input) {
    Mat pyr = new Mat();
    Mat timg = new Mat();

    // Down-scale and up-scale the image to filter out small noises
    Imgproc.pyrDown(input, pyr, new Size(input.cols() / 2, input.rows() / 2));
    Imgproc.pyrUp(pyr, timg, input.size());
    // Apply Canny with a threshold of 50
    Imgproc.Canny(timg, timg, 0, 50, 5, true);

    // Dilate canny output to remove potential holes between edge segments
    Imgproc.dilate(timg, timg, new Mat(), new Point(-1, -1), 1);

    // find contours and store them all as a list
    Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
    Imgproc.findContours(timg, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    List<MatOfPoint> squaresResult = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {

        // Approximate contour with accuracy proportional to the contour
        // perimeter
        MatOfPoint2f contour = new MatOfPoint2f(contours.get(i).toArray());
        MatOfPoint2f approx = new MatOfPoint2f();
        double epsilon = Imgproc.arcLength(contour, true) * 0.02;
        boolean closed = true;
        Imgproc.approxPolyDP(contour, approx, epsilon, closed);
        List<Point> approxCurveList = approx.toList();

        // Square contours should have 4 vertices after approximation
        // relatively large area (to filter out noisy contours)
        // and be convex.
        // Note: absolute value of an area is used because
        // area may be positive or negative - in accordance with the
        // contour orientation
        boolean aproxSize = approx.rows() == 4;
        boolean largeArea = Math.abs(Imgproc.contourArea(approx)) > 200;
        boolean isConvex = Imgproc.isContourConvex(new MatOfPoint(approx.toArray()));
        if (aproxSize && largeArea && isConvex) {
            double maxCosine = 0;
            for (int j = 2; j < 5; j++) {
                // Find the maximum cosine of the angle between joint edges
                double cosine = Math.abs(getAngle(approxCurveList.get(j % 4), approxCurveList.get(j - 2),
                        approxCurveList.get(j - 1)));
                maxCosine = Math.max(maxCosine, cosine);
            }
            // If cosines of all angles are small
            // (all angles are ~90 degree) then write quandrange
            // vertices to resultant sequence
            if (maxCosine < 0.3) {
                Point[] points = approx.toArray();
                squaresResult.add(new MatOfPoint(points));
            }
        }
    }
    return squaresResult;
}

// angle: helper function.
// Finds a cosine of angle between vectors from pt0->pt1 and from pt0->pt2.
private static double getAngle(Point point1, Point point2, Point point0) {
    double dx1 = point1.x - point0.x;
    double dy1 = point1.y - point0.y;
    double dx2 = point2.x - point0.x;
    double dy2 = point2.y - point0.y;
    return (dx1 * dx2 + dy1 * dy2) / Math.sqrt((dx1 * dx1 + dy1 * dy1) * (dx2 * dx2 + dy2 * dy2) + 1e-10);
}

public static Mat drawSquares(Mat image, List<MatOfPoint> squares) {
    Mat result = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(image, result, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGB);
    int thickness = 2;
    Core.polylines(result, squares, false, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), thickness);
    return result;
}
}
```

Example of result :

[image]
[image]


**... though, it doesn't work so great for smaller images :**
[image][image]

**Maybe some enhancements can be suggested? Or how to make the algorithm faster in case I have a batch of images to process?**

Comment: Can you give more informations like do you want to use OpenCV ? do you have the rectangle positions ? what did you try yet ?

Comment: I didn't try using OpenCV, but that's ok,any libraries are welcome, as long as its fast... I tried to identify rectangle-like shapes in the image..but that didn't worked very well. No, I don't have the rectangle positions.

Comment: Is this the **exact** input image (that is, can this serve as a test case)? In how far did your attempted approach not "work very well"?

Comment: Yes, this can be used as a test case. My approach is not efficient... I thought about segmenting the image by "spaces" : in this exact case I would get every image containing a character except for the ones in rectangles I would get the whole rectangle.. after that I would need to check every image if the image is a character or a rectangle.. for rectangles I would need to extract the text..

Comment: *pls-send-me-the-code* questions are not well received by the community, and putting a bounty on it is an even bigger mistake.

Comment: @karlphillip I understand, thanks for the advice.. I wanted to change the bounty message before, but I think it's not possible :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did the following program in c++ using opencv (I'm not familiar with java+opencv). I've included the output for the two sample images that you have provided. You may have to adjust the thresholds in the contour filtering section for some other images.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // load image as grayscale
    Mat im = imread(INPUT_FILE, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    Mat morph;
    // morphological closing with a column filter : retain only large vertical edges
    Mat morphKernelV = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(1, 7));
    morphologyEx(im, morph, MORPH_CLOSE, morphKernelV);

    Mat bwV;
    // binarize: will contain only large vertical edges
    threshold(morph, bwV, 0, 255.0, CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);

    // morphological closing with a row filter : retain only large horizontal edges
    Mat morphKernelH = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(7, 1));
    morphologyEx(im, morph, MORPH_CLOSE, morphKernelH);

    Mat bwH;
    // binarize: will contain only large horizontal edges
    threshold(morph, bwH, 0, 255.0, CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);

    // combine the virtical and horizontal edges
    Mat bw = bwV & bwH;
    threshold(bw, bw, 128.0, 255.0, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);

    // just for illustration
    Mat rgb;
    cvtColor(im, rgb, CV_GRAY2BGR);

    // find contours
    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    findContours(bw, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
    // filter contours by area to obtain boxes
    double areaThL = bw.rows * .04 * bw.cols * .06;
    double areaThH = bw.rows * .7 * bw.cols * .7;
    double area = 0;
    for(int idx = 0; idx >= 0; idx = hierarchy[idx][0])
    {
        area = contourArea(contours[idx]); 
        if (area > areaThL && area < areaThH)
        {
            drawContours(rgb, contours, idx, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2, 8, hierarchy);
            // take bounding rectangle. better to use filled countour as a mask
            // to extract the rectangle because then you won't get any stray elements
            Rect rect = boundingRect(contours[idx]);
            cout << "rect: (" << rect.x << ", " << rect.y << ") " << rect.width << " x " << rect.height << endl;
            Mat imRect(im, rect);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Result for the first image:

[image]

Result for the second image:

[image]

Comment: +1 This is a really good answer. It provides code to solve problem, some explanation of what it does and the resulting images. Good job!

Comment: Great answer. Can you please post the result for this images : [1-image](http://oi59.tinypic.com/14y0j91.jpg), [2-image](http://oi60.tinypic.com/21kiekw.jpg). I implemented your approach, and this are the results -> [1-image](http://oi59.tinypic.com/fdyoie.jpg) and [2-image](http://oi58.tinypic.com/e0jr69.jpg)

Comment: My results look the same as yours. I didn't target the solution for a complex image as the second one. If you take a look at the intermediate result images you'll notice that Otsu thresholding left out the box around the word, and if you observe the gray image histogram, you'll see it is not bimodal, so Otsu thresholding wouldn't do well. Even if you get the thresholding right, you'd still need a mechanism to filter out false hits. A word segmentation approach would do better for complex images.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure whether "real" image processing skills are necessary.

Once you start tackling this problem with OpenCV, Sobel/Canny filters, edge detections and Hough transforms, it starts becoming rather involved. But **maybe** all this is not necessary here.

It all depends on how "predictable" the input is. That's why I asked in the comments whether the image can serve as a test case. IF the rectangles are always axis-aligned and don't have noise, distortions and interruptions, this can be solved with some trivial loops and pixel comparisons.

So IF you have potentially noisy or distorted input images, then ... good luck, you may have to acquire quite some image processing skills. If the image is not distorted or noisy, a solution like this one might be sufficient:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class RectangleInImageTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        final BufferedImage image = convertToARGB(ImageIO.read(new File("gcnc2.jpg")));
        final List<BufferedImage> subImages = scan(image);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI(image, subImages);
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI(
        BufferedImage image,
        List<BufferedImage> subImages)
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        f.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)),
            BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,0));
        for (BufferedImage subImage : subImages)
        {
            p.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(subImage)));
        }
        JPanel pp = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,1));
        pp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 100));
        pp.add(new JScrollPane(p));
        f.getContentPane().add(pp, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.setSize(800,800);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }


    public static BufferedImage convertToARGB(BufferedImage image)
    {
        BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(
            image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = newImage.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        g.dispose();
        return newImage;
    }    

    private static List<BufferedImage> scan(BufferedImage image)
    {
        List<BufferedImage> result = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();
        for (int y=0; y<h; y++)
        {
            for (int x=0; x<w; x++)
            {
                int rgb = image.getRGB(x, y);
                if (!isBlack(rgb))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if (!isUpperLeftCorner(image, x, y))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                Rectangle rectangle = extractRectangle(image, x,y);
                if (!isValidRectangle(rectangle))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                System.out.println("Rectangle "+rectangle);

                BufferedImage part = new BufferedImage(
                    rectangle.width-2, rectangle.height-2, 
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                Graphics2D g = part.createGraphics();
                g.drawImage(image, 
                    0, 0, rectangle.width-2, rectangle.height-2,
                    x+1, y+1, x+rectangle.width-1, y+rectangle.height-1, null);
                g.dispose();
                result.add(part);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static boolean isBlack(int rgb)
    {
        final int threshold = 128;
        int r = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        int g = (rgb >>  8) & 0xFF;
        int b = (rgb      ) & 0xFF;
        return 
            r < threshold &&
            g < threshold &&
            b < threshold;
    }

    private static boolean isUpperLeftCorner(BufferedImage image, int x, int y)
    {
        if (!isValidAndWhite(image, x-1, y  )) return false;
        if (!isValidAndWhite(image, x  , y-1)) return false;
        if (!isValidAndWhite(image, x-1, y-1)) return false;
        if (!isValidAndWhite(image, x+1, y-1)) return false;
        if (!isValidAndWhite(image, x-1, y+1)) return false;
        if (!isValidAndWhite(image, x+1, y+1)) return false;
        return true;
    }

    private static boolean isValidAndWhite(
        BufferedImage image, int x, int y)
    {
        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();
        if (x < 0 || x >= w)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (y < 0 || y >= h)
        {
            return false;
        }
        int rgb = image.getRGB(x, y);
        return !isBlack(rgb);
    }


    private static Rectangle extractRectangle(
        BufferedImage image, int x0, int y0)
    {
        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();

        int x1 = x0;
        int y1 = y0;
        for (int y=y0; y<h; y++)
        {
            int rgb = image.getRGB(x0, y);
            if (!isBlack(rgb))
            {
                y1 = y;
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int x=x0; x<w; x++)
        {
            int rgb = image.getRGB(x, y0);
            if (!isBlack(rgb))
            {
                x1 = x;
                break;
            }
        }
        return new Rectangle(x0, y0, x1-x0, y1-y0);  
    }


    private static boolean isValidRectangle(Rectangle r)
    {
        final int minWidth = 16;
        final int minHeight = 8;
        return r.width >= minWidth && r.height >= minHeight;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes that's also true :)

Comment: It works great on this test case.. but ok, I didn't think ahead.. if the image is going to be a scanned copy , then inevitably it's going to have some distortions and noise... so I probably need a different approach... thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's an algorithm that I demonstrated on a [similar project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20624819/176769) using OpenCV:

- **[Find](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7732392/176769) the [squares](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7756000/176769)** on the original image;
- **[Extract (crop)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15748297/176769) the squares** found so each become a new image;
- [Perform](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10107970/176769) [OCR detection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10618222/176769) on [each image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20710396/176769).

Most of these references are not in Java, but I assume you have the skills to convert C/C++ code to Java (btw, `cv::Mat` is equivalent to `IplImage`).

Comment: Thanks for the references, it helped a lot! Can you please take a look at the code and the result after edit : can I make any improvements to make the method be more accurate? (If you take a look at the first result the squares are a little bit cropped) and maybe make it work for smaller images?

Comment: and I don't understand why it doesn't work for the image in the original question.. I get this result [image](http://oi59.tinypic.com/2u94neq.jpg)

Comment: @IulianRosca Check **dhanushka** answer!

Answer (score 2):

first of all I hope you are already aware of some image processing because you will need some of this to continue :)

Here is a link about ways to do it : https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3324/how-to-detect-edges-and-rectangles

But to sum up the most used method would be to use a **Canny** (edges detector) and them to apply **Hough** in order to detect the straight line and considering the results find the rectangle. In fact Hough is usually used to detect straight line and a rectangle is just 4 straight lines with an angle of 90° between each of them. So using all of this you may be able to improve your research ;)

Hope it will help ;)

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to perform connected component analysis after binarization using adaptive method. After that, calculate the median width of the connected component, if the connected component width is 5 times larger than the median width, then this connected component is the square we are looking for. The following codes are used to illustrate this idea

```
    Mat im = imread(inputFileName,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
Mat outputIm(im.rows,im.cols,CV_8U, Scalar(0));


    Mat bi;



// step 1: adaptive thresholding 
adaptiveThreshold(im,bi,255,ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,THRESH_BINARY,7,50);

threshold(bi, bi, 128.0, 255.0, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);


    // step 2: connected component analysis
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;

findContours(bi, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL , CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);  

    // step 3: analyze these blobs
double area;
std::vector<double> areaArray;
for(int i=0; i<contours.size(); i++)
{
    cv::Rect rect = boundingRect(contours[i]);
    area = rect.width;
    areaArray.push_back(area);
}
std::vector<double> sortedAreaArray;
sortedAreaArray = areaArray;
size_t n = sortedAreaArray.size() / 2;
    nth_element(sortedAreaArray.begin(), sortedAreaArray.begin()+n, sortedAreaArray.end());

double medianArea = sortedAreaArray[n];

for(int i=0; i<contours.size(); i++)
{
    if(areaArray[i]>5*medianArea)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<contours[i].size(); j++)
        {
            int x = contours[i][j].x;
            int y = contours[i][j].y;
            int pos = x+y*bi.cols;
            outputIm.data[pos]=255;
        }
    }

}
imwrite(outputFileName,outputIm);
```

The output rectangles can be shown:

[image]
[image]

Comment: is this going to work for images that are scanned? the rectangles might not be perfect, maybe the lines could be erased a little bit..

Comment: @lulian Rosca It would work. If the lines are not well detected. One possiblity is to perform dilation for the binary image so that the line can be fully detected.

Comment: can you please provide some code example how to do that?