# Shape context matching in OpenCV

Tags: image-processing, opencv

Have OpenCV implementation of shape context matching? I've found only matchShapes() function which do not work for me. I want to get from shape context matching set of corresponding features. Is it good idea to compare and find rotation and displacement of detected contour on two different images.

Also some example code will be very helpfull for me.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I want to detect for example pink square, and in the second case pen. Other examples could be squares with some holes, stars etc.

Comment: Sharing some example images will be very helpful for you as well.

Comment: I think it is not so neccesary cause I want implement some algorithms. I have no particular case I want to use it. But I uploaded some example photos.

Comment: [Template matching](http://nashruddin.com/template-matching-in-opencv-with-example.html) with internal OpenCV functions requires a reference image. For a specific implementation on how to detect squares, [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7732392/176769)

Comment: As I said I want to match also more complicated contours. Satisfying effect will be for me as described here http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/shape/sc_digits.html

Comment: Edited your question to adjust the images sizes so people don't run away from it. Nice reference, all you have to do now is implement their technique. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for editing. As I said in question I would like rather to find some good implementation.

Comment: Your problem appears well suited for: a. Pairwise Geometrical Histograms (PGH)
b. Hierarchical Matching of Contours. OPenCV offers methods to get both.

Comment: But how to extract rotation and displacement from it. I suppose that it could be done by modyfying tree in some way. But what way shifting sequence to build tree from different point? Pairwaise geometrical histograms gives poor information about rotation I think.

Answer (score 2):

The basic steps of Image Processing is

Image Acquisition > Preprocessing > Segmentation > Representation > Recognition

And what you are asking for seems to lie within the representation part os this general algorithm. You want some features that descripes the objects you are interested in, right? Before sharing what I've done for simple hand-gesture recognition, I would like you to consider what you actually need. A lot of times simplicity will make it a lot easier. Consider a fixed color on your objects, consider background subtraction (these two main ties to preprocessing and segmentation). As for representation, what features are you interested in? and can you exclude the need of some of these features.

My project group and I have taken a simple approach to preprocessing and segmentation, choosing a green glove for our hand. Here's and example of the glove, camera and detection on the screen:
[image: We have - The green clove seen on the right, the camera in the bottom left corner, and the screen showing livefeed output, as well as come features that we printed in the console]

We have used a threshold on defects,  and specified it to find defects from fingers, and we have calculated the ratio of a rotated rectangular boundingbox, to see how quadratic our blod is. With only four different hand gestures chosen, we are able to distinguish these with only these two features.

The functions we have used, and the measurements are all available in the [documentation on structural analysis](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html) for OpenCV, and for acces of values in vectors (which we've used a lot), can be found in [the documentation for vectors in c++](http://new.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/)

I hope you can use the train of thought put into this; if you want more specific info I'll be happy to comment, Enjoy.

Comment: It's nice answer, but my question and problem is different. Now I am looking for extracting rotatnion and displacement from PGH and Hierarchical matching methods.