# Which algorithm can I use for quadrilater/cube detection?

Tags: c++, c, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

For a project, I have to detect a cube with a webcam. I think that OpenCV could be a good solution to find out where is it (real-time).
I'm new in the computer vision domain, and I wonder which algo can I use ? Hough ?
I've seen this video (quite impressive!): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytvO2dijZ7A
Do you know how he was able to do it ?

Thank you a lot for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the result as in the video, you have given, you can use [`squares.cpp`](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/branches/2.3/opencv/samples/cpp/squares.cpp) that comes with OpenCV samples. (It is for images. Hope you can do it for videos.)

Other useful SO on this topic are:

1) [OpenCV C++/Obj-C: Detecting a sheet of paper / Square Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667818/opencv-c-obj-c-detecting-a-sheet-of-paper-square-detection/8863060#8863060)

2) [Square detection doesn't find squares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731742/square-detection-doesnt-find-squares)

Comment: I've tried squares.c, but it isn't working as well as I excpeted :s, actually, when my cube is not correcly aligned, it doesn't work.
I've seen some 3d markless video but looks quite hard to implement.
My dream is to implement the object detection at this page : http://cvlab.epfl.ch/~lepetit/. It s written there is some source but I didn't find any.

Comment: @tomylab: well, you could add more details, what is problem while using squares.c? what you expected really? May be you could add a link to picture you are working on. Difficult to explain further without more details.

Comment: @karlphillip: that saves me a lot of time from explaining already explained things. And also, let questioner do a little work of his own. I am on the opinion that we should not destroy a questioner's quest to find the answers.

Comment: @tomylab : can you be a little more specific? Your link contain a lot of things and papers. Which one do you want to implement? There is one real time object detection topic in it, but it also contain link to its source code.

Comment: I think he is talking about the work on **Real-Time Object Detection**. @tomylab Have you read the papers?

Comment: @karlphillip: Do you have a gmail account? I would like to have a chat with you. Mail me on arkiazm@gmail.com when you are free.

Comment: @arkiaz did u find the source code? My ultimate dream is to detect the cube with a webcam. But I'm not sure that the square.c is enough efficient. What do u think ?

Comment: @karlphillip Yes, Real-Time Object Detection. Just a few lines. I've seen that they work with Matlab. Is there an other way to detect object without mathlab ?

Comment: try this link for source code: http://campar.in.tum.de/personal/hinterst/index/downloads.html

Comment: Thank you! But do you know the difference between DOT - Version/
GEPARD - Version/LEOPAR - Version?

Comment: Leopard and Gepard are there the version of the apple'os and dot the dot net?