# how to detect known objects in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, real-time, detection, shapes, template-matching

I am try to draw shapes in the window in real time. The shapes are like tangle ,rectangle ,circle , half or circle and "Z" in the screen using yellow color. The size and the shape may not be same to the original image. But Program know all the original shapes. Because they are predefined. I want to know how i can identify the correct shape. as an example,

[image]

is there possible way to do this? can I use template matching for this? Please help me with this..

Comment: ya you can do template matching ..or you can try to fit rectangles or ellipses to your drawn shape...after fitting check what it closely resembles and then decide on the shape..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [different methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9660582/176769) to detect each shape. Check these:

- [Ellipse detection with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10985330/176769)
- [Square detection doesn't find squares](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7732392/176769)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It really helpful for me. But how i can identify shapes like "Z". I try to develop this application for disabled users. So I want to detect different shapes.

Comment: There are different techniques to accomplish this, you might to take a look at match template, flann, sift and others. The [OpenCV tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html) offer examples and a decent explanation of these methods. Also, Stackoverflow has a nice database of questions similar to yours.

Comment: @ Karlphillip
Thanks for your reply. Your ideas are really helpful for me. Again Thanks lot.

Comment: You are free to ask new questions in new threads, but we have this rule, so let's keep 1 question per thread. Your new question involves Artificial Intelligence, so I will suggest you really ask it on a new thread so the AI experts can answer you. Good luck.