# How do I run this Open CV square detection code with an image

Tags: c++, opencv, object-detection

So I am trying to run the code given in this link and what is said is:
"Once compiled, run the application with the following syntax: ./app "
but I don't exactly understand what this means.

I run the program and it successfully runs, but it simply opens the cmd and exits immediately.

So my question is how can I get the program to work in conjunction with an image, to actually do the square detection on an image?

link: [Square detection doesn't find squares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731742/square-detection-doesnt-find-squares/7732392#7732392)

Comment: I haven't tried it, but the linked answer doesn't say just `./app`, it says `./app <image>`. Did you pass the image file name to the app?

Comment: No this is my problem I don't exactly know how to do that.